# how to access DOM element outside the component in JS file in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, react-component

I have an application in which I need to access the input by the user outside the component. I don't want to store the input in the state also, so it should be stateless. I tried passing like below.

```
<input ref="usrname" input id="userName" ref="user" type="text" class="login-input" placeholder="Enter User ID" 
onChange={(e)=> {GlobalUserModel.setUserName(e.target.value); e.preventDefault();this.obj=GlobalUserModel}}/>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-login" class="submit" id="submit" name="submit" onClick={ApiCall.bind(GlobalUserModel)} >Login</button>
```

And in LoginModel.js

```
class LoginModel {
username;
constructor(){
}
setUserName(username1) {
debugger;
this.username = username1;
console.log("username1 : ",username1)
return this.username;
}

getUserName(){
return this.username;
}
};
const GlobalUserModel=new LoginModel();
export default GlobalUserModel;
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can pass in a `ref` to the from the parent to the child to get access the input element

Answer (score 0):

For the first I'd like you to know that it's a **bad practice** to have to access a DOM outside from the component. It may produce side effects and suitable bugs.

In your case, you can pass `onChange` prop and invoke it when the `input` has been changed

Comment: I want to separate presentation and data layer. can you provide an example snippet of the approach you are mentioning?